# Why many characters cannot be displayed when I change LC_ALL from en_US to en_US.utf8

Tags: bash, encoding, utf-8

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=en_US
```

Everything is fine:

```
$ man du

DU(1)                            User Commands                            DU(1)

NAME
       du - estimate file space usage

SYNOPSIS
       du [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Summarize disk usage of each FILE, recursively for directories.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

       -a, --all
              write counts for all files, not just directories

       --apparent-size
              print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the appar-
              ent  size  is  usually  smaller, it may be larger due to holes in
              ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation,  indirect  blocks,  and
              the like

       -B, --block-size=SIZE use SIZE-byte blocks
```

When I change `LC_ALL`:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
$ locale
LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

It's becoming bad now:

```
$ man du

DU(1)                            User Commands                            DU(1)

NAME
       du - estimate file space usage

SYNOPSIS
       du [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Summarize disk usage of each FILE, recursively for directories.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

       -a, --all
              write counts for all files, not just directories

       --apparent-size
              print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the appar-
              ent  size  is  usually  smaller, it may be larger due to holes in
              (<E2><80><98>sparse<E2><80><99>) files, internal fragmentation,  indirect  blocks,  and
              the like

       -B, --block-size=SIZE use SIZE-byte blocks
```

The `'` character becomes `<E2><80><98>`, why?

Answer (score 1):

By setting your locale to UTF-8, you've told the shell and other programs to output text encoded in UTF-8 to the terminal. However, your terminal does not understand UTF-8, and so is displaying the 3-byte sequence rather than the actual symbol for U+2018, "Left Single Quotation Mark". You'll need to configure your terminal emulator to accept UTF-8 output, or find one that does.

Comment: I am using SecureCRT, and I have configured it's character encoding to be UTF-8, but the error still happens. And what encoding will be used if I use `en_US` with `.utf8`?